# One document library but want to show different library filters on the same page

Tags: web-part, document-library

I am currently using one document library, so as to avoid the same type of file being use in different SharePoint libraries.

The issue that I have is when I create a sub page, I am often asked to show more than one library on a page. that being the content from the 'master library' but filtered based on a field.

All is well up to this point. The problem comes when I try to set the filter on a different criteria for each library list on the page:

1. If I see to "set as default" all the library start up showing the same content.
2. How can I set each web part document library list to store a particular default and keep this on start-up?
3. I don't want to create multiple document libraries if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filtered view of the library, then when you add your webpart to the page you can select what view you want to display in the webpart.  So if you want multiple webparts showing different stuff you will need to setup multiple views of the document library.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by setting up multiple views of the document library.... Adding a new library web part in each new section of the page.  I did this and set the filter on the library to my preference (Set As Default) but all library web parts show the same content on the page.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint, to change the view of a web part, please follow the steps as below:

1. Go to the page where you added web part and click the gear icon on the upper right corner.
2. Select Edit page.
3. Edit your Library Web Part.
4. Expand the Selected View and choose the view you want to use.
5. Click Apply to check the outcome.
6. Click OK and save the changes.

[image]

For Modern Pages in SharePoint Online, please check below reference.

**Reference**:

1. [Use the Document Library web part](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/use-the-document-library-web-part-a9dfecc3-2050-4528-9f00-2c5afc5731b0).

Comment: Have you tried this solution? You can achieve your requirement by creating multiple views in your document library by specifying filters and adding App webpart of document library on the SharePoint page.

Answer (score 0):

no one's actually answered his question; it's partly a function of maybe not understanding what he's asking. I have the same need: develop multiple pages each with a distinct filtered view of a single document library. In SharePoint 2010 Ganesh is correct. But in Modern SharePoint pages using a Document Library web part leads to a world of pain and unnecessary work. Use the Highlighted Content Web Part for this:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd

Answer (score 0):

When you add a document library to a page, click the Edit button, and in modern sharepoint you can type the folder name of the folder you want to display on that page. Repeat this for each page you add the document library to. I prefer this to the highlighted content.